# How to replace multine values to empty string in linux?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, vi

[image]

I wanted to change this value

```
{
"data":"correctValue",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "otherValue": "incorrectValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
"data":"correctValue"
}
```

Comment: Is this a question about `vi`?  The tag is linux, so I'll assume you're using `vim`.  Put the cursor on the comma and type `d%`. This is pretty primitive, so it may work in vanilla `vi` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, if instead of deleting the attributes you want to keep `.data`, you can do:

```
jq '{data: .data}' input-file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq` to process json files. You want to remove attributes in the top level object, which can be achieved by

```
jq 'del(.attributes)' file.json
```